# run jquery before document is ready

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('*:lang(English)').hide();
$('*:lang(French)').hide();
});
```

What I need is that every element with attribute lang="English" or lang="French" to be hidden initially.

but now when I load my website it glitches. since html starts being rendered before  $(document).ready becomes well "ready". So as a consequence all elements with the above specified attribute will be shown for a split second.

Is there a way to put a handler on every `*:lang(English)` before document is ready so I don't see anymore glitches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably remove the jQuery and do this with CSS:

```
*:lang(en), *:lang(fr) {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, if you want to show only one language, for example, do *that* with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*:lang(fr)').show();
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, that solved it....Quick question though, what is the difference between this and using visibility property?

Comment: `visibility: hidden` makes it invisible, but it still takes up space. `display: none` is as if it were never even there, taking up no space.